# migrate email with imapsync

Tags: email, zimbra, imapsync

I try to migrate emails from an ice warp server to zimbra and I use imapsync for  it. With the following command I get  the error message

```
--host1 option must be used, run /usr/bin/imapsync --help for help
```

the command what I try to run

```
imapsync \ --buffersize 8192000 --nosyncacls --subscribe --syncinternaldates \ --host1 myip1--user1 myuser --password1 mypassword --ssl1 --port1 993 \ --host2 myip --user2 myuser --password2 mypassword --ssl1 --port2 993
```

Comment: Try it without the ` \ `s ?

Comment: I'll put it as an answer then...

Comment: ok I will accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `\` from the command, I'd imagine the `--buffersize 8192000 --nosyncacls --subscribe --syncinternaldates` commands are optional, but the `--host` is not.

Answer (score 0):

Remove useless:

```
--buffersize 8192000 
--nosyncacls 
--syncinternaldates
--port1 993
```

Also if host2 needs ssl then replace --port 993 by --ssl2